# Orientation of photos sent from Android devices?

Tags: pictures, orientation, android

I'm seeing all photos taken on and sent from Android devices rotated 90 deg clockwise from their original orientation.

Is this a known issue, or is it Too Localized?  If known, is there a workaround?

Comment: If it really only happens from Android phones, I would assume it has something to do with that OS

Comment: @Tom whatever are you talking about?  90 degrees, of course!  What fool would put 45 when he meant 90?

Comment: @Will: Ah, glad you fixed it. If you sent it to your computer you should see what orientation the original device is saving it in. Most likely Android is displaying it differently or something like that...

Comment: Try comparing the full EXIF data on a WinPhone photo and an Android one.  It would be interesting to see if they used different fields for this.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't the ideal fix, there are free apps like Fantasia Painter Free in the WP7 marketplace that you can use to rotate those photos.

With the new Windows Phone 8, basic image manipulation like rotating the image is now supported.